# nested associations in form not updating properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following situation. A contact has_many lead_profiles. I have a new lead_profile form, where the user enters information about the lead_profile and contact. However, I am using a jquery autofill plugin, in that if the contact already exists, the user can select it and then a hidden input id attribute is created to indicate that it's no longer a new contact:

```
  # controller
  def new
    @lead_profile = LeadProfile.new
    @contact = @lead_profile.build_contact name: "Donato"
  end

  # view
  <%= form_for @lead_profile do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :contact do |builder| %>
      <%= builder.text_field :name %>
      <%= builder.text_field :address %>
    <% end %>    
  <% end %> 

  # javascript
  $('#lead_profile_contact_attributes_address').bind('typeahead:selected', function(obj, datum, name) {  
    var $parent = $("#lead_profile_contact_attributes_address").closest(".form-group");
    $parent.after('<input name="lead_profile[contact_attributes][id]" type="hidden" value="' + contact.id + '">')
  });
```

Now when the form is submit to create, I need to determine if the contact exists or not. Note that if I didn't do this, and sent an id attribute for contact back to server, Rails raises an exception "Couldn't find Contact with ID=10 for LeadProfile with ID=". So I must override the contact_attributes= call:

```
  def contact_attributes=(params)
    if params[:id].present?
      self.contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    else
      self.contact = Contact.new params
    end
  end
```

Above, I determine if the contact is a new contact or an existing one (which would be the case if the user populates it from javascript autocomplete).

All seems to work fine. If the contact is new, a new contact is created in database with attributes from params hash. If contact is existing, the existing contact is updated with attributes from form. And in both cases, the lead_profiles record is associated with that contact.

But now a problem occurs when I want to update the lead_profile. I use the same form for update as I did for new:

```
 <%= form_for @lead_profile do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :contact do |builder| %>
      <%= builder.text_field :name %>
      <%= builder.text_field :address %>
    <% end %>    
  <% end %>
```

If I update the contact info in the lead_profile form, the contact is not updated in the database, because of this override that I needed:

```
  def contact_attributes=(params)
    if params[:id].present?
      self.contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    else
      self.contact = Contact.new params
    end
  end
```

If I remove that, then the contact would be updated, however then I would get the other issue when creating a new contact:

```
Couldn't find Contact with ID=10 for LeadProfile with ID=
```

I really want to save this two models together in a single form, and Rails shouldn't restrict me on that. What can I do at this point?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have one solution working. Remember that when you do an update on a model, it automatically does an update on associations as soon as you invoke save on the model. By default, it will update its association attributes based on the input in the fields_for nested form. However, as soon as you override that default and invoke find, then obviously nothing will be updated on the association:

```
def contact_attributes=(params)
    if params[:id].present?
      self.contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    else
      self.contact = Contact.new params
    end
  end
```

The solution is to somehow distinguish when you are updating a model and when you are dynamically building an existing model association through the form via autocomplete. I used a virtual attribute for that purpose. If the field is being dynamicalyl generated by autocomplete, this is not a rails default and you have to handle it yourself:

```
  model Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :autocompleted
  end

  model LeadProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
      def contact_attributes=(params)
        # this contact model was autocompleted via javascript
        if params[:id].present? && params[:autocompleted].present?
        self.contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
      else
        # self.contact = Contact.new params
        super
      end
    end
```

In all other cases, call super and let Rails do its default behavior.

Comment: found another use case for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess try adding the contact instance in your fields_for call i.e.

```
<%= f.fields_for :contact,@contact do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.text_field :name %>
  <%= builder.text_field :address %>
<% end %>
```

Let me know if that works. I've often had random issues with nested forms and sometimes explicitly setting the target object of the nested form solves the problem